# How to make animated cell expansion?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, tableview, cell

I have cell with **UILabel** and **Button**. For the first time label have **three rows**.

When I tap on the **button**, number of lines increase and my cell change size, but without animation. how I can correct it?

My code inside cell:

```
func buttonTap() {
    if textIsHide == true {
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 100
        textIsHide = false
        button.setTitle(.localized(for: "posters_postercard_hide"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 3
        textIsHide = true
        button.setTitle(.localized(for: "posters_postercard_showmore"), for: .normal)
    }
    delegate?.reloadRows()
    descriptionLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

And this is my UIView, where I update my table:

```
extension PosterCardView: PosterCardDataManagerDelegate {
func reloadRows() {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to put something like `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths..` in between the `beginUpdates ` and `endUpdates `

Comment: @Tj3n but I don't know how to get indexPath in my view(

Answer (score 0):

```
        func buttonTap() {
    if textIsHide == true {
        withAnimation {
            descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 100
            textIsHide = false
            button.setTitle(.localized(for: "posters_postercard_hide"), for: .normal)
        }
        
    } else {
        withAnimation{
            descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 3
            textIsHide = true
            button.setTitle(.localized(for: "posters_postercard_showmore"), for: .normal)
        }
        
    }
    delegate?.reloadRows()
    descriptionLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

have you ever tried with an animation?